# WPF Caliburn MEF application & DI

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I'm experimenting with using Caliburn and MEF in a WPF application. My MEF knowledge is sketchy at best.

Here's the Bootstrapper:

```
class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
  public Bootstrapper()
  {
     Initialize();
  }

  protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
     DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
  }

  protected override void Configure()
  {
     //An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs  
     var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

     //Adds all the parts found in the same assembly as the Program class  
     catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));

     //Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog  
     container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

     var batch = new CompositionBatch();
     batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
     batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
     batch.AddExportedValue(container);

     container.Compose(batch);
  }

  protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
  {
     string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
     var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

     if (exports.Any())
        return exports.First();

     throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
  }

  protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
  {
     return container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
  }

  protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
  {
     container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
  }
```

}

Here's the shellview:

```
<Window x:Class="MefCaliburn.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MefCaliburn"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ShellView" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Menu"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Messages"></ContentControl>

</Grid>
```

The IShell interface:

```
public interface IShell
{
}
```

Here's my shell view model:

```
namespace MefCaliburn
{
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
  private readonly IEventAggregator _events;

  UserViewModel uvm;

  [ImportingConstructor]   
  public ShellViewModel(MenuViewModel menu, MessagesViewModel mess, IEventAggregator eventaggregator)
  {
     Messages = mess;
     Menu = menu;
     _events = eventaggregator;
  }

  public MessagesViewModel Messages
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public MenuViewModel Menu
  {
     get; set;
  }

  public void LaunchUserViewModel()
  {
     uvm = new UserViewModel();
  }
}
}
```

So when the Boostrapper overridden method

```
  protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
     DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
  }
```

gets called, my ShellViewModel constructor is called and the *Menu* and *Messages* view models are *Injected*. This is an example of dependency injection, correct?

In my case the Menu & Messages view models are created along with the shell.
But if a new view model

```
[Export(typeof(UserViewModel))]
public class UserViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
  private readonly IEventAggregator _events;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public UserViewModel(IEventAggregator eventaggregator)
  {
     _events = eventaggregator;
  }
}
```

is created when the user presses a button on the MenuView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MefCaliburn.MenuView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MefCaliburn"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="ONE" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action LaunchUserViewModel()]"></Button>
        <Button Content="TWO"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This *UserViewModel* will be publishing events to the *MessagesViewModel*, I'm going to need the IEventAggregator. Yes, I can just pass it in explicitly to the constructor, but what I'm trying to understand is why MEF won't inject it.

Am I trying to use MEF in a manner it's not intended? Is MEF only meant to be used when the application starts up for those view models that are known to be required?

Comment: Did you add `IEventAggregator` as an exported value? Something like this I mean: `AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());`

Comment: I forgot to add my bootstrapper code to my original question post. It's there now. As you can see the IEventAggregator is being added to the composition container.

Comment: Make sure that `UserViewModel` is also exported. You have to export it to be able to import values into it. Also don't forget to rebuild your solution.

Comment: So I added the Export[] as you suggested, but the line where i'm trying to create a new instance of UserViewModel is still underlined in red with the following error: error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'eventaggregator' of 'UserViewModel.UserViewModel(IEventAggregator)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a little confused. First of all I think that you don't really want to be using `MEF` in the first place, but I will get to that later. You try to create a new viewmodel in your `LaunchUserViewModel`. The whole idea of `MEF` and `Dependency Injection` is to get rid of it. As you can see here `new UserViewModel()` when you try to create a new instance you **have to** supply all the required parameters. But the whole idea is to let the framework do the work and supply them for us. So first of all we have to get rid of the `new` keyword and think about instantiating it differently. Let's look at your example:

This  is ok. You Export a module of certain type.

```
[Export(typeof(IUserViewModel))]
public class UserViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
  private readonly IEventAggregator _events;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public UserViewModel(IEventAggregator eventaggregator)
  {
     _events = eventaggregator;
  }
}

public interface IUserViewModel {
    void SomeMethod();
}
```

So what do we usually do when we export something? We import it somewhere else:

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    [Import]
    public IUserViewModel Uvm { get; set; }

   public void LaunchUserViewModel()
   {
      Uvm.SomeMethod(); // Your Uvm is already created 
   } 
}
```

As you can see we completed removed `new` keyword. This means that the `ShellViewModel` doesn't know what class exactly it's gonna import. And that's the beauty of it. You can swap implementations any time you want, and you don't have to change `ShellViewModel`
What happens here is `AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());` notifies `MEF`, hey, here's a class that something might want. Later when you do `[ImportingConstructor]`, `MEF` looks for the classes that the constructor needs and if it has them, it injects them for you.

Now, I think you just wanted `Dependency Injection` and got into the wrong framework. Although `MEF` allows you to use `DI`, it is much more powerful. It uses a concept of modules so that you can build modular applications. It is very useful when you want to allow people to write plugins for your application.

What it would look like is:
You would only show plugins what you want them to show, so you would create a project called `API` which would store only contracts(interfaces). Then you would have you program's `Core` and users would supply `Plugins`. Users would only see `API`, not `Core`, and you would load their plugins knowing that they actually implement `API` interfaces you told them to implement.

You don't need `MEF` to use `Dependency Injection`. `Caliburn.Micro` has built in container, but you can also use [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), and many more.

I hope it makes sense. It's a vast subject.

**EDIT:**

I created a very basic [project](https://github.com/fcin/Caliburn.Micro-DI-Example)  that uses `Caliburn.Micro` with Dependecy injection. Maybe it will help you to understand it better.

Comment: I was "alot confused". I started with MEF because I cut and paste from an existing example. I think I'll take your advice and look into caliburns built in container. thanks.

Comment: I will soon update my project to show how to do more difficult stuff, such us importing viewModels and displaying them in windows/popup's. Also if my answer solved your problem, be sure to mark is as answered, so it's easier for others to find solution to this problem.

Comment: I would have marked it answered by you already, but i have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: @JanaAndropov No problem, I'm glad I could help. I updated my project with more examples :)

Comment: Hi i've been looking at your example project. How do I handle the situation where each printer view model is shown depending on user selection? If I add PrinterViewModel, and ExtraPrinterViewModel to the contrainer. I'll need to access the container later to activate the viewmodel in question.

Comment: @JanaAndropov You can just register a factory and create instances depending on passed parameter. This way you create another layer of abstraction. I updated my repo with example with factory injection.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I highly recommend you give up MEF and use an IoC container that's much less clunky and easier to use (like [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html)).  But if you want to go MEF route you will need to export the EventAggregator inside your boostrapper class as following:

```
private CompositionContainer _container;

protected override void Configure()
{
   _container = new CompositionContainer(new ApplicationCatalog());

   var batch = new CompositionBatch();

   batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
   batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
   batch.AddExportedValue(_container);

   _container.Compose(batch);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add my bootstrapper code to my original question post. It's there now. As you can see the IEventAggregator is being added to the composition container. Also, I might actually make use the MEF when it comes to adding support for plugins.

Comment: @JanaAndropov If that's the case, like FCin suggests add an MEF export for UserViewModel.  Also, you will need to use _windowManager to actually display a window (by calling _windowManager.ShowWindow, or ShowDialog) inside your Launch function.  I also recommend this article to get up to speed with MEF: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF